# Third party getting access to industrial machine on network

Tags: cisco, remote-access, windows-sbs-2011

I need to allow an outside company to get access to an industrial machine that is on the internal network of our company.

The network setup is a Cisco router that is owned and controlled by our IP (it has ports 443 and 1723 open) and inside we have an SBS 2011 and Win Server 2008 R2. The SBS is the Domain Controller, file server and most everything else, the 2008 R2 server is just used for Navision.

What I would like is for the external party to have access to that industrial machine (lets say internal IP 192.168.1.20) and nothing else.

What would be a good way to go about doing this?

Using Remote Desktop? VPN? If VPN then which ones, I do not fully trust PPTP, getting our ISP to open up ports for other VPN's shouldn't be that big of a deal. Any other options?

Comment: The Cisco router you mentioned seems to be operating a VPN already.

Comment: Well, I do believe (this is a network set up by another person, I am new to this network) that the port 1723 is forwarded to the SBS.

Comment: What about an IPSec VPN tunnel between remote company and yours ? This is usually what i do when i have to deal with such issue in my companie...Opening RDP through Internet (even if filtered by source IP) would be a bad idea IMHO

Comment: Sounds good, can the VPN somehow restrict the user to only one computer or do I need to create an AD account for him and use that to point him to the right computer?

Comment: Your VPN IPSec Gateway should handle this for you if it has an embedded Firewall (as mine). If not, route the VPN Network through Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using SBS 2011, you could allow the remote company to use the Remote Web Access website - this will allow them to make an RDP connection to the internal computer via a web page.

In order to do this, you will need to set them up as a user in the SBS Console, give them access to RWA, and remote rights to that particular computer.

I'm assuming that your SBS server has been fully configured properly, and has the RWA running properly. You already have port 443 open, so I'm assuming it is set up.

More info about RWA [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/03/10/introduction-to-sbs-2011-remote-web-access-rwa.aspx)